# How to transform the mains from 110 V to 220 V and do proper grouding for house on limestone rocks near the ocean?

Tags: electrical, grounding-and-bonding

I would like some guidelines and advice on how to transform the mains supply from 110 V to 220 V for an entire house. This means the wall outlets should permanently deliver 220 V instead of 110 V (main priority). Also, power outtages are common and the house is not grounded at the moment; it would be nice to have that fixed as well. How to achieve all this? I would like to receive solutions that:

- address which key components are needed
- address some theory behind the transition from 110 V to 220 V
- apply to the house itself rather than indiviual devices (for example one transformer for each household appliance is not what I am looking for)

## Background

This house is located in Central America on an island that is currently transitioning from 110 V towards 220 V.

## Earth grounding

The house is not grounded. I know that grounding is sometimes done with a grounding rod. However, this house is literally built on limestone rocks which makes a grounding rod useless in this scenario. Is it possible to plunge a grounding rod into the sea? Any other options?
It may be useful to mention that the house is located near the sea; from the garden you can jump right into the sea, which lies 10 meter below the garden surface.

## Power outtages

Once the mains has been changed into 220 V, will it be possible to connect any UPS to the mains in case of power outtages?

## Research

I have a background in electrical engineering, so obviously I have done some research. However I can find very little info on how to transform an entire house from 110 V into 220 V and how to perform proper grounding for a house that is located on limestome rocks near the ocean.

Comment: Do not rise the voltage before you know the insulations of the wires and outlet sockets  are rated for the higher voltage. In addition the sockets for 220V shoukd prevent plugging 110V devices to 220V - just to keep out at least one reason for firefighting. An advice: Get a qualified contractor who knows the subject and local electricity code.  The contractor surely knows also how groundings should be made and calculates which kind of voltage doubling device you need. If you are lucky you need nothing , you could get 220V by only switching the wires differently.  DO NOT TRY IT by YOURSELF!

Comment: (continued) Everything you do should be in accordance with the code and what the supplier of the electricity wants.

Comment: Do you know if your utility is delivering a single P+N of 220-240VAC, or split-phase 120/240VAC?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is use a transformer large enough to supply your full home.   However as stated earlier get a qualified electrician to evaluate what you have and what will have to be replaced. You did not state the age of the home, this will have a big impact on how it is currently wired. Also many of the 220V systems are actually 3 phase where power is frome phase to phase, not phase to ground which may prevent 3 phase appliances from working. This has a big impact on the grounding method used although 220V appliances will work with either method. Check further in what configuration they are changing to, so you do not have to do this twice. You may be scheduled for a change sooner than you expect, you might want to check into that. After you get through this check the pro's and con's of making the change. This just touches the surface, a book could be written on doing this.